# Create "growing ripples" loading animation - OutOfMemoryException

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-animation, animationdrawable

I want to display this animation in an Android app:

> [image]

So I created a `<animation-list>` to do so. It uses 46 frames, each one consisting of a 200x200px `png`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim_loading_ripple_frame_0" android:duration="45" />
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim_loading_ripple_frame_1" android:duration="45" />
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim_loading_ripple_frame_2" android:duration="45" />
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim_loading_ripple_frame_3" android:duration="45" />
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim_loading_ripple_frame_4" android:duration="45" />
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim_loading_ripple_frame_5" android:duration="45" />
               ...
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim_loading_ripple_frame_45" android:duration="45" />
    </animation-list>
```

Then I set this as the `background` of an `ImageView` and start the animation using

```
AnimationDrawable loadingAnimation = 
    (AnimationDrawable) loadingAnimationView.getBackground();
loadingAnimation.start();
```

Everything works perfect, except for the fact that the app sometimes crashes due to an `OutOfMemoryException`! It seems that the memory requirements by this kind of animation are quite high, as I've read others experiencing the same issues.

Then I thought I could probably just make each frame into an XML `shape` drawable, so I tried experimenting, but I can't figure out how to make the circles change size - they always occupy the whole width of the view.

I tried doing something like this

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <padding android:top="30dp" android:right="30dp" android:bottom="30dp" android:left="30dp" />
        <size
            android:width="100dp"
            android:height="100dp" />
        <stroke
            android:color="#0F0"
            android:width="4dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

And also using a `layer-list` to define another `shape` in the same XML file but with a different size, thinking that would cause the circle to become smaller, but they both ended up occupying 100% of the view.

Also, I'm not sure if the `AnimationDrawable` will actually use less memory if I define the frames in XML as opposed to a series of `png` images? Perhaps I'll still run into the same memory usage issue?

What alternatives do I have? If time wasn't an issue, I'd try to work out a custom View, but it seems like a lot of work just for this animation.

Comment: How about an `ImageView` with a vector image and use a scale animation on the `ImageView` itself for the growing circle? At the end of one animation, swap in the alternate vector image and run a scale animation back from small to large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ScaleAnimation` solution provided by Ves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52684220/930640) will work, but I figured I might as well dive into it and make a proper (and I guess quite more efficient) custom `View`. Especially when dealing with multiple "ripples".

[image]

This is the entire View class, tweaks to the ripples can be made in `init()` to change colors, number of ripples, etc.

*RippleView.java*

```
public class RippleView extends View implements ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {
    public static final String TAG = "RippleView";


    private class Ripple {
        AnimatorSet mAnimatorSet;
        ValueAnimator mRadiusAnimator;
        ValueAnimator mAlphaAnimator;
        Paint mPaint;

        Ripple(float startRadiusFraction, float stopRadiusFraction, float startAlpha, float stopAlpha, int color, long delay, long duration, float strokeWidth, ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener updateListener){
            mRadiusAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(startRadiusFraction, stopRadiusFraction);
            mRadiusAnimator.setDuration(duration);
            mRadiusAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
            mRadiusAnimator.addUpdateListener(updateListener);
            mRadiusAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

            mAlphaAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(startAlpha, stopAlpha);
            mAlphaAnimator.setDuration(duration);
            mAlphaAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
            mAlphaAnimator.addUpdateListener(updateListener);
            mAlphaAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

            mAnimatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
            mAnimatorSet.playTogether(mRadiusAnimator, mAlphaAnimator);
            mAnimatorSet.setStartDelay(delay);

            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setColor(color);
            mPaint.setAlpha((int)(255*startAlpha));
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        }

        void draw(Canvas canvas, int centerX, int centerY, float radiusMultiplicator){
            mPaint.setAlpha( (int)(255*(float)mAlphaAnimator.getAnimatedValue()) );
            canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, (float)mRadiusAnimator.getAnimatedValue()*radiusMultiplicator, mPaint);
        }

        void startAnimation(){
            mAnimatorSet.start();
        }

        void stopAnimation(){
            mAnimatorSet.cancel();
        }
    }

    private List<Ripple> mRipples = new ArrayList<>();



    public RippleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public RippleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public RippleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if( isInEditMode() )
            return;

        /*
        Tweak your ripples here!
        */
        mRipples = new ArrayList<>();
        mRipples.add(new Ripple(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, Color.RED, 0, 2000, 4, this));
        mRipples.add(new Ripple(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, Color.WHITE, 500, 2000, 4, this));
    }


    public void startAnimation() {
        setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        for (Ripple ripple : mRipples) {
            ripple.startAnimation();
        }
    }

    public void stopAnimation() {
        for (Ripple ripple : mRipples) {
            ripple.stopAnimation();
        }

        setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int centerX = getWidth()/2;
        int centerY = getHeight()/2;
        int radiusMultiplicator = getWidth()/2;

        for (Ripple ripple : mRipples) {
            ripple.draw(canvas, centerX, centerY, radiusMultiplicator);
        }
    }
}
```

Just call `.startAnimation()` on the `RippleView` to start the animation.

```
RippleView r = findViewById(R.id.rippleView);
r.startAnimation();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ScaleAnimation to change your size. I created an ImageView and used the shape you defined above:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/circle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/circle"/>
```

It is slightly different than you wanted because I did not bother to find the center point to set the animation. It is scaling from the upper left corner. (0,0)

```
  ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.circle);
  float startScale = 0.5f;
  float endScale = 3.0f;
  Animation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation( startScale, endScale, 
                              startScale, endScale,
                              Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0,
                              Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0);
  scaleAnim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
  scaleAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REPEAT);
  scaleAnim.setDuration(2000);
  iv.setAnimation(scaleAnim);
  scaleAnim.start();
```

You can similarly animation the color using a ValueAnimation.